# ¿Cómo puedo abrir y cerrar el teclado virtual (soft-keyboard)?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

Quiero mostrar el teclado virtual (soft-keyboard) para algún `EditText` que tiene *focus* y que ha sido obtenido programáticamente (sin que haya sido presionado). Y cerrarlo cuando ocurre algún evento como presionar un `Button` en la pantalla.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Para mostrar el teclado virtual (soft-keyboard) forzadamente, se puede usar:

```
EditText editText= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
editText.requestFocus(); //Asegurar que editText tiene focus
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.showSoftInput(yourEditText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

Sin embargo, si se quiere quitar el *focus* de `editText` es necesario que otra `View` obtenga el *focus*. Así que si no se tiene otra `View` habrá que crear otra `View` vacía y darle el *focus* a ella.

---

Para cerrar el teclado virtual, se puede usar:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(yourEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Comment: Hola, me funciona el metodo para ocultar teclado pero no el de mostrar , lo he probado en emulador y en dispositivos reales y no sale ningun error en el logcat,no se que podria estar pasando.

Comment: ¿Tienes algún componente como `EditText` que obtenga el _focus_?. Esto es una parte importante del proceso.

Comment: Mi actividad tiene dos EditText (uno para numero de telefono y otro de ) y al inicio le pongo focus al primero y luego uso la invocacion del teclado, luego uso un TedxtWatcher para cerrar el teclado una vez que el primer textview llegue a tener 9 caracteres luego pasando el focus al segundo textview y funciona bien esa parte

Comment: ¿Y en qué parte es cuando no funciona?

Comment: al inicio, logro poner el focus en el primer TextView pero no aparece el teclado

Comment: ¿Qué tal si intentas esto? `getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);`?

Comment: It worked, thank you :3

Answer (score 8):

Traducido de la original: **[Cerrar / ocultar el teclado en pantalla Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard)**

Puedes forzar a esconder el teclado virtual usando la clase `InputMethodManager`,
llamando el método `hideSoftInputFromWindow`, enviando el token de la ventana que contiene la vista enfocada.

```
// Compruebe si ninguna vista tiene el foco.
View view = this.getCurrentFocus();
if (view != null) {  
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

Esto forzará al teclado a ocultarse en todas las situaciones. En algunos casos se tendrá que pasar `InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY` como segundo parámetro para asegurar que únicamente se oculte el teclado cuando el usuario no forza explícitamente que aparezca (manteniendo pulsado menú).

Sin embargo desde `Android 4.1+`, se tiene que agregar `view.clearFocus()` para que funcione correctamente:

```
View view = this.getCurrentFocus();
view.clearFocus();
if (view != null) {  
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

En Kotlin me funcionó lo siguiente por si lo necesitan, usan la correspondiente entre la actividad o el fragment en dependecia de donde quieran hacer la llamada

```
fun YourFragmentName.hideKeyboard() {
    view?.let { activity?.hideKeyboard(it) }
}

fun YoActivityName.hideKeyboard() {
    hideKeyboard(currentFocus ?: View(this))
}

fun Context.hideKeyboard(view: View) {
    val inputMethodManager = getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
    inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.windowToken, 0)
}
```

Ejemplo de uso en un fragment:

```
view.btn_login.setOnClickListener {
            hideKeyboard()
}
```