# Android Studio / Ocultar teclado con la propiedad android:focusable

Tags: android, android-studio, teclado, hide

Seguro saben que al abrir una actividad que tenga un edit text, automáticamente este se seleccionará y abrirá por defecto el teclado.

**Llevo mucho tiempo ocultandolo con este método:**

```
public void ocultar(){
    View vieww = getActivity().getCurrentFocus();
    if(vieww != null){
        InputMethodManager input = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        input.hideSoftInputFromWindow(vieww.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
}
```

**Hoy descubrí como ahorrarme tener que escribir eso, usando la siguiente propiedad XML en el edit text**

```
android:focusable="false"
```

**Funciona perfecto.** Ya no se selecciona el edit text automáticamente pero acá **aparece** el problema. Ahora mi EditText **no puede** ser seleccionado por lo que, solucioné un problema pero me encontré con este **otro**.

Me gustaría saber como abrir una actividad sin que el teclado se abra **automáticamente** y teniendo la posibilidad de interactuar con un EditText como es normal.

```
<EditText
     android:id="@+id/edit"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:focusable="false"/>
```

**Gracias por leer!**

Comment: No entiendo bien lo que quieres hacer. ¿Se muestra el teclado al lanzar la activity y no cuando pulsas en uno de los controles de escribir texto (`EditText`)? Eso no debería pasar. Si lo que quieres es ocultar el teclado cuando terminas de escribir en el `EditText`, puedes asociar el código que tenías antes para ocultarlo al evento `onKey` del `EditText` cuando la acción es `ACTION_DOWN` y el `keyCode` es `KEYCODE_ENTER`

Comment: ¿Podrías poner como tienes el xml?

Comment: NO. Intento evitar que el molesto teclado no se muestre cuando entro en una actividad. Solo quiero que se muestre cuando el usuario presione en el edit text.  (Ya adjunté el código xml de un edit text)

Comment: @TomasM quita por favor  android:focusable="false" y haz uso de view.clearFocus() , revisa mi respuesta, saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Es casí "correcto" lo que realizas

```
public void ocultar(){
    View vieww = getActivity().getCurrentFocus();
    if(vieww != null){
        InputMethodManager input = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        input.hideSoftInputFromWindow(vieww.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
}
```

sin embargo, **ahora desde Android 4.1 es muy importante agregar `view.clearFocus()` para que funcione correctamente**:

```
public void ocultar(){
    View vieww = getActivity().getCurrentFocus();

    vieww.clearFocus(); //*Agregar!

    if(vieww != null){
        InputMethodManager input = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        input.hideSoftInputFromWindow(vieww.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
}
```

Revisa esta respuesta [Cerrar / ocultar el teclado en pantalla Android](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/300/95)

Comment: De donde sale ese "view"? Lo pongo pero no existe en mi actividad. Lo reemplaze por mi "vieww" y me pone este error: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.clearFocus()' on a null object reference . Además ya mencioné que el método ocultar() que uso me funciona. Solo que quiero evitar tener que usarlo porque CREO que es posible lograrlo con alguna propiedad xml

Comment: @TomasM , perdón es : vieww.clearFocus();, edite mi respuesta, saludos.

Comment: Como dije, me sale el error null pointer exception

Answer (score 0):

Vale, mira. Lo que he hecho ha sido crear una `activity` con un `EditText` y he hecho lo siguiente:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="206dp"
        android:layout_height="73dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Añade esta línea:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"
```

Espero que te sea útil.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta pero no fue útil. Cuando abro la app , el puntero sigue cayendo sobre el edit text y el teclado se abre automáticamente.

Answer (score 0):

En tu Manifest debes de decirle a tu actividad como se comportara el teclado:

```
  <application ... >
    <activity
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" ... >
        ...
    </activity>
    ...
</application>
```

El teclado de software siempre está oculto cuando la ventana principal de la actividad tiene foco de entrada.

[Fuente](https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/visibility)

Comment: Gracias por comentar. No solo que no me funcionó para ocultar el teclado (se sigue abriendo) sino que también ya estoy usando esa propiedad con "adjustResize".